# How To Call Stored Procedure in NestJs+TypeOrm (Backend)

Tags: nestjs

I have stored procedure in oracle database, and I want to call it in NestJs.
How do I to call stored procedure in NestJs?

This is my stored procedure

```
PROCEDURE pipeline_critical (
        i_main_company IN NUMBER,
        o_value OUT NUMBER
   ) AS
   BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(A.PIPELINE_ID) AS IGNORED_PIPELINE 
    INTO o_value
    FROM T_PIPELINE A
    LEFT JOIN T_PIPELINE_PRODUCT P ON P.PIPELINE_ID = A.PIPELINE_ID
    WHERE 
        1 = ( CASE WHEN
                i_main_company <> 3
                AND A.MAIN_COMPANY_ID = i_main_company
                AND TO_CHAR(A.EST_DELIVERY,'YYYY') >= TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY') - 1
                AND A.PIPELINE_STATUS_ID IN (1,2,3)
                AND TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(A.UPDATE_DATE,3),'YYYYMM') < TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYYMM')
                AND P.PAID_DATE IS NULL THEN 1
            WHEN
                i_main_company = 3
                AND TO_CHAR(A.EST_DELIVERY,'YYYY') >= TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY') - 1
                AND A.PIPELINE_STATUS_ID IN (1,2,3)
                AND TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(A.UPDATE_DATE,3),'YYYYMM') < TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYYMM')
                AND P.PAID_DATE IS NULL THEN 1
            END
        );
   END pipeline_critical;
```

Comment: Try using QueryRunner with running a Raw SQL query calling your procedure.

Answer (score 13):

I am migrating Javascript/sequealize Backend, and I am testing my needs.
This is a simple example that's work for me:

This is stored procedure

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_prueba
@email varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    select * from tbusua where emai_usua=@email
END
```

In NESTJS - Controller

```ts
import { Controller, Get, Param } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UsuariosService } from './usuarios.service';
import { async } from 'rxjs/internal/scheduler/async';
import { Usuario } from './usuarios.entity';


@Controller('Usuarios')
export class UsuariosController {
    constructor(private readonly UsuariosService: UsuariosService) { }

    @Get('/:email')
    async find(@Param('email') email): Promise <Usuario[]>{
        return await this.UsuariosService.find(email);
    }
}
```

And in the NESTJS - TypeORM Backend in the service

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Usuario } from './usuarios.entity';
import { Repository, Db, EntityManager } from 'typeorm';

@Injectable()
export class UsuariosService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(Usuario)
        private readonly usuariosRepository: Repository<Usuario>) { }

    async find(email: string): Promise<Usuario[]>{
        return await this.usuariosRepository.query("sp_prueba @email='"+email +"'");
    }
}
```

this work for me

Comment: I think you're prone to sql injection in your current code `"sp_prueba @email='"+email +"'"`

Comment: What if there is no repository to query?

Comment: To avoid sql injection you can do the following; query("CALL my_spr(?)", [value1])

Comment: @JaimeGinorio The only way it worked for me on Oracle was using ":PARAM_NAME" as the placeholder

Answer (score 4):

There does not appear to be any functionality built in to TypeORM related to stored procedures specifically. However, you can execute a stored procedure using a [`Connection`](https://typeorm.io/#/connection-api) or a [`QueryRunner`](https://typeorm.io/#/query-runner) and passing the name of the procedure and any parameters directly:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Connection } from 'typeorm';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(
    private readonly connection: Connection,
    // ...
  ) {}

  async execProcedure(someParam: number) {
    const result = await this.connection.query(
      'EXEC procedures.MyProcedure @0', [someParam]
    );
    // ... do something with the result
  }
}
```

Note that `Connection#query` and `QueryRunner#query` return type `any`, but from what I can tell the return value looks something like this: `[ { '': 'result' } ]`, where result is the last value `SELECT`ed in the procedure. You may want to annotate `result` in the example code as such to preserve type safety.

Also note that this method isn't really specific to NestJS's interface with TypeORM; as long as you have a connection or query runner then you can execute any raw query directly.

Comment: Connection is deprecated,any other option?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me calling Oracle stored procedure using Node and typOrm and NestJs.

Simple stored procedure.

```
create or replace package body xxx_test is
procedure do_test(outnumber OUT number)
is
    begin
        select 42 into outnumber from dual;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Date ' || outnumber);
    end;
end;
```

Code To execute:-

```
  async execProcedure(someParam: number) {
    const oracledb = require('oracledb');
    const sql = 'BEGIN\n' +
        '  XXX_TEST.DO_TEST(:P1);\n' +
        'END;';
    const result = await this.connection.query(
        sql, [{ dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, type: oracledb.NUMBER }]
    );
    console.log('Input Param ' + someParam);
    console.log('Output Results ' + result);
  }
```

Calling above with  - this.execProcedure(1);

Result

```
Input Param 1
Output Results 42
```

Answer (score -1):

Checkout this npm package

[dk-typeorm-spcall](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dk-typeorm-spcall)

This will help you to call any stored procedure easily.

Just need to import the required provider and call specific database function.

Read package [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dk-typeorm-spcall).

Thanks :)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/33213151)

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks for the feedback answer is updated please check.